# How do I get the Google +1 button to give a preview of the article rather than the top HTML on the page?

Tags: google-plus-one

Google Plus lists all your +1s with a small preview of the webpage that was +1ed. Techcrunch and Mashable's previews come up as the first sentence of the article, however for me it just takes the first HTML on the page (which in my case is navigation). How can I get it to target the article for this preview rather than the navigation?

I have looked through the [API](http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/) and couldnt find anything that would do what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google finally released how to do it. http://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plus-snippet

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have three options to avoid G+ trying a best guess.

1) (prefered) Mark up your site with microdata. Please refer to http://schema.org and possibly the Google Webmaster Tools help section on microdata and the Opera Developer resources.

It will look something like:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Article Title</h1> <!-- snippet title -->
  <img itemprop="image" src="image-url"></img> <!-- the snippet icon -->
  <p itemprop="description">Snippet text.</p>
</body>
```

The idea is to mark up the parts that you already uses as base for your snippet. Yahoo, MS Bing, Google and a few other search engines will try to honour this for their search snippets as well, as well as future browser versions, e.g. for bookmarks.

2) Use the facebook Open Graph protocol (which is not valid html, but makes your snippets compatible with facebook "shares").

It will look like  (put this in your  section)

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Your snippet title"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="url://of-your-snippet-image.jpeg"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Your snippet text goes here"/>
```

3) Set the title and description meta tags.

```
<meta name="title" content="Your snippet title" />
<meta name="description" content="Your snippet text goes here">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *itemprop* tags to tell +1 what you want to use.

There's many ways to go about it:

You can add the following tags to your opening HTML declaration:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
```

and then add the following meta descriptors:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="Your article's title" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="Your article's description or excerpt" />
```

and finally add this to the image you want to use:

```
<img itemprop="image" src="image.jpg" />
```